# Oracle Retail Merchandising System SEC_FORM_ACTION_ROLE Table's Relationship

Tags: oracle

I have a Security Form problem in Oracle Retail Merchandising System application. As I known, with the `SEC_FORM_ACTION_ROLE` table I can setup Security Form for an user.But I don't know what are the `Role` and the `User` tables which the `SEC_FORM_ACTION_ROLE`reference to.

Comment: @Justin Cave you're all right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try NAV_ELEMENT_MODE, NAV_ELEMENT_MODE_ROLE, SEC_FORM_ACTION, FORM_LINK, FORM_LINKS_ROLE. Please seek from Oracle Website or the web the manual Oracle Retail 13, Security Architecture and look at pages 11 thru 17. You'll be fine.